# print file extension using java

Tags: java

I'm new in java

I'm trying print file's extension.

`(String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE")`, this is where my files are placed with different extensions.

The code I have written, shows this error:

> "you cannot assign variable to extesion"

Can anyone help me?

```
String str= (String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE");
String extension = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);

if (extension = csv) { 
    System.out.println("good");
}
else if (extesion = bad) { 
    System.out.println("already processed");
}
else {   
    System.out.println("check"); 
}
```

Comment: A single `=` means assignment, not equality. You also want to be using `.equals()` for String comparison, not `==`.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change this:

```
  if (extension = csv)
```

With:

```
   if (extension.equals("csv"))
```

And this:

```
 (extesion = bad)
```

With this:

```
  (extension.equals("bad"))
```

Use `equals()` instead of `=` ,because This method compares this string to the specified object. The result is true if and only if the argument is not null and is a String object that represents the same sequence of characters as this object.

But `=` is a simple assignment operator.

Comment: That second one has a typo in it (it's in the OP too), it should be `extension` not `extesion`

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks little misguided, 
1. Use `equals` instead of `=`

```
if (extension.equals("csv"))    
{ 
   System.out.println("good");    
}    
else if (extension.equals("bad"))    
{ 
  System.out.println("already processed");
}    
else 
{   
  System.out.println("check");     
}
```

**Edit more info**
`=` is assignment operator which is used to assign values to variables
`==` is comparison operator which compares two object by reference and produces result `true` or `false` 
`if` we always need boolean condition which tells compiler when to execute statements inside `if`

In our case we have used `equals` instead of `==` as we are trying to compare strings and if we use `==` then it will compare them be reference not by the value contained in variable.